# Multiply checkbox data attribute with input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Each time I check any checkbox, I want to multiply the data-price attribute with the value of the input field associated with the checkbox. I need to calculate the sum of all these multiplications.

HTML:

```
<input class="selectproduct" type="checkbox" name="item0" data-price="5"/>First 
<input type="text" class="qty0" name="qty0"/>
<br/>
<input class="selectproduct" type="checkbox" name="item1" data-price="7"/>Second 
<input type="text" class="qty1" name="qty1"/>
<br/>
Total Price: $<span class="price">0</span>
```

JS:

```
$('.selectproduct').on("change", function () {
    var totalPrice = 0;

    $('.selectproduct:checked').each(function () {
        totalPrice += parseInt($(this).data('price'), 10);
    });

    $('.price').html(totalPrice);
});
```

I'm currently able to sum the price according to the checkbox but I can't figure out how to multiply it with the associated input field whenever there is a change. How do I constantly update the sum whenever the input field changes?

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/600rzptn/

Comment: Are those `<input>` elements wrapped in a common parent at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like following.

```js
$('.selectproduct').change(function() {
  var totalPrice = 0;

  $('.selectproduct:checked').each(function() {
    totalPrice += $(this).data('price') * $(this).next('input').val();
  });

  $('.price').html(totalPrice);
});

//to change total price on changing textbox value
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function() {
  $('.selectproduct:first').change();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="selectproduct" type="checkbox" name="item0" data-price="5" />First
<input type="text" name="qty0" />
<br/>
<input class="selectproduct" type="checkbox" name="item1" data-price="7" />Second
<input type="text" name="qty1" />
<br/> 
Total Price: $<span class="price">0</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your calculation line to:

```
totalPrice += parseInt($(this).data('price'), 10) * $(this).next().val();
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/600rzptn/1/)**

Comment: This doesn't update the sum when i change the input field though. Assuming my first checkbox is checked and the input value is 1, the sum will change to $5, which is correct. However, when I change the input value to 2, the sum doesn't change. How can I make the sum change whenever it input value changes?

Comment: You can just change the selector to `$('.selectproduct, input[type="text"]')`. https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/600rzptn/2/